# Генерация обратного элемента в поле Галуа

Tags: python, алгоритм, криптография

Имеем поле Галуа **GF(2<sup>409</sup>)**, и неприводимый полином над полем :

**f(x) = x<sup>409</sup> + x<sup>15</sup> + x<sup>6</sup> + x + 1**
*//Коэффициенты при степенях только 0 или 1*

Пускай у меня есть какой-то полином ***a(x)*** в этом поле.
Вопрос: Как мне найти ***обратный к "а(x)",относительно f(x)*** элемент , используя именно **алгоритм Евклида**, а не возведение элемента "а(x)" в степень 2<sup>409</sup>-2.

*//Алгоритм поиска обратного элемента пишу на Python используя полиномиальный базис, а на нём возведение в степень работает слишком долго
//Проблемы возникают при введении операции деления на полиномах*

Comment: в чём у вас трудности? Хотите ускорить существующий код? Хотите руками реализовать [gcd-like алгоритм на Питоне](http://stackoverflow.com/a/147539/4279)? Или готовой библиотекой воспользоваться, [к примеру `GF.invert` в sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/internals.html#sympy.polys.domains.domain.Domain.invert)

Comment: Трудность в том,что возведение в степень 2^409 - 2 слишком долго работает.
Алгоритм Эвклида гораздо быстрее.
Готовой бибилотекой пользоваться не хочу,так как делаю это чисто в образовательных целях.

Comment: если вопрос о производительности, то приведите код, который правильный результат получает (пускай медленно) и укажите насколько вы его хотите ускорить (`2**409` не должно заметное время занимать). Можете посмотреть [как sympy реализует gf_gcd](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/_modules/sympy/polys/galoistools.html#gf_gcd) (для образования--не думаю, что это особо эффективный вариант). *"Коэффициенты при степенях только 0 или 1"* намекает, что полиномы можно эффективно целыми числами представить.

Answer (score 2):

**2<sup>409</sup>-2** - это число, содержащее 409 установленных битов и один сброшенный (предпоследний). Это значит, что для быстрого возведения в эту степень элемента **a(x)** требуется **408** операций возведения в квадрат и **408** операций умножения над полиномами 409-го порядка по модулю **f(x)**.

Для умножения полиномов нужно **409 * 410 / 2** умножений, порядок произведения будет 818. Для приведения его к модулю **f(x)** по методу деления "уголком" требуется 409*4 вычитаний, что практически не влияет на производительность.

Итого: **2 * 408 * 409 * 410 / 2 = 68 417 520** умножений.

Реальная проблема - в разрядности данных, поскольку при каждом возведении полинома в квадрат сумма его коэффициентов (равная значению полинома при **x = 1**) также возводится в квадрат, что увеличивает исходную разрядность на **409 log<sub>2</sub> a(1)** бит и в итоге "утяжеляет" алгоритм, как минимум, на 2 порядка.

Остальное - детали реализации.